# Go Fullscreen with HTML5 Video on iPad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, fullscreen

I'm trying to play and go fullscreen for an HTML5 video element on an iPad/iPhone via JavaScript, but when I try videoElement.webkitEnterFullScreen(), I see an INVALID_STATE_ERR: Dom Exception 11.

My [Code](http://pastebin.com/u3BCTkNe)

For [Example](http://plygrnd.evanculver.com/video.html)

Now, it looks like specific support for [this behavior](http://gitorious.org/webkit/webkit/commit/31ef81f6d0b8d19cd3ea35853b5e95c323c71deb) was added here:

which specifically prevents going fullscreen without a user gesture.

**My question:**

Is there a workaround for this?

I see that Vimeo's HTML5 video player is mimicking this behavior somehow as seen [here](http://tylermanson.com/commercial/the-sartorialist/)
(on iPad/iPhone)

So, it seems it is possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: On the iphone, video is always full screen, the browser just runs quicktime externally when you click on the link to a video

Comment: I think what Evan is asking for is to play the video in the "fullscreen" mode, which doesn't require the user to browse to the file (like what happens when you click the fullscreen control on the iPad). That's how Vimeo works on the iPhone.

Comment: now you can use `webkitEnterFullscreen` to trigger fullsreen on iphone

Answer (score 9):

Testing on iOS simulator Ipad

Hope I can help someone:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var vid;

    function init() {
        vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
        vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", goFullscreen, false); 
    }

    function goFullscreen() {
        vid.webkitEnterFullscreen();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        init();

        $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){
            $('#myVideo')[0].webkitExitFullScreen();
        });
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Fullscreen Video</h1>
    <video src="movie.mp4" id="myVideo" autoplay controls >
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know, there are better ways to post code here.

http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: More info at Safari's Developer Library (the above code was taken nearly verbatim from here): https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW13

Comment: This is old, webkitEnterFullScreen is obsolte and must use webkitRequestFullscreen and then webkitExitFullScreen must be replaced by ocument.webkitCancelFullScreen(). Also this is actually not supported on Safari iOS, check http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked for me

```
- (void) makeHTML5VideoFullscreen {
    if(webView) {
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.querySelector('video').webkitEnterFullscreen();"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('video').webkitEnterFullscreen();`

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer.